# How are inline functions compiled to assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, inline

I have some code C++ that loops to update values, and out of curiousity I wanted to see the assembly that made up the loop of the body. This led me to experiment a little bit with how inlining looks like after compilation (**the compiler is MSVC with O2**).

However, when I compared the instruction set to how I thought it should look like when it's actually inlined, I was a bit confused by what I found. Here is some context:

```
template<typename T>
struct ClassWithInline
{
    Values *v;

    ClassWithInline(Values *v) : v{ v } {}
    T inlineMe(T * const c) const
    {
        // some function of *c, using v->some_constants
    }
};
```

The `Values` object is just something that contains constants. `ClassWithInline` is a member of another object, `Owner`, and owner has a function `callTheInline`:

```
struct Owner
{

    ClassWithInline<double> a;
    Values *v;

    Owner(Values *v) : a{ ClassWithInline<double>(v) }, v{ v } {}
    void callTheInline()
    {
        double *ptr = new double[100];
        double *dptr = new double[100];

        size_t the_end = std::floor(1000 + log(100000));

        for (size_t n = 0; n < the_end; ++n)
        {
            dptr[n] = a.inlineMe(ptr + n);
        }

        ClassWithInline<double> b(v);
        for (size_t n = 0; n < the_end; ++n)
        {
            dptr[n] = b.inlineMe(ptr + n);
        }
    }
};
```

(The wonky end iteration number is so the compiler doesn't know the size of the loop at compile time and introduce some other optimizations.)

Now when I look at the assembly generated for those for loops, they are dramatically different; in fact the one invoking `inlineMe` from `a` has twice as many assembly instructions. How do I bridge this disparity?

`a.inlineMe(ptr + n);`

```
000000013F642094  mov         rbp,rbx  
000000013F642097  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],r15  
000000013F64209C  sub         rbp,rsi  
000000013F64209F  lea         r15,[r9-3]  
000000013F6420A3  mov         r14,rsi  
000000013F6420A6  lea         r10,[rbx+8]  
000000013F6420AA  sub         r14,rbx  
000000013F6420AD  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
000000013F6420B0  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rdi]  
000000013F6420B3  lea         rdx,[r14+r10]  
000000013F6420B7  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [r10-8]  
000000013F6420BD  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rdx+rbp-10h]  
000000013F6420C3  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [r10]  
000000013F6420C8  movsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rdi+8]  
000000013F6420CD  lea         rax,[rcx+r8]  
000000013F6420D1  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F6420D5  mulsd       xmm2,xmm2  
000000013F6420D9  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8]  
000000013F6420DE  mov         rax,r8  
000000013F6420E1  sub         rax,rcx  
000000013F6420E4  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8]  
000000013F6420E9  subsd       xmm1,xmm0  
000000013F6420ED  divsd       xmm1,xmm2  
000000013F6420F1  movsd       mmword ptr [r14+r10-8],xmm1  
000000013F6420F8  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [r10+8]  
000000013F6420FE  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [r10-8]  
000000013F642104  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rdi]  
000000013F642107  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [r10]  
000000013F64210C  movsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rdi+8]  
000000013F642111  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F642115  lea         rax,[rcx+r8]  
000000013F642119  mulsd       xmm2,xmm2  
000000013F64211D  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+8]  
000000013F642123  mov         rax,r8  
000000013F642126  sub         rax,rcx  
000000013F642129  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+8]  
000000013F64212F  subsd       xmm1,xmm0  
000000013F642133  divsd       xmm1,xmm2  
000000013F642137  movsd       mmword ptr [rdx],xmm1  
000000013F64213B  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [r10+10h]  
000000013F642141  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [r10]  
000000013F642146  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rdi]  
000000013F642149  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [r10+8]  
000000013F64214F  movsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rdi+8]  
000000013F642154  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F642158  lea         rax,[rcx+r8]  
000000013F64215C  mulsd       xmm2,xmm2  
000000013F642160  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+10h]  
000000013F642166  mov         rax,r8  
000000013F642169  sub         rax,rcx  
000000013F64216C  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+10h]  
000000013F642172  subsd       xmm1,xmm0  
000000013F642176  divsd       xmm1,xmm2  
000000013F64217A  movsd       mmword ptr [r14+r10+8],xmm1  
000000013F642181  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [r10+18h]  
000000013F642187  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [r10+8]  
000000013F64218D  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rdi]  
000000013F642190  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [r10+10h]  
000000013F642196  movsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rdi+8]  
000000013F64219B  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F64219F  lea         rax,[rcx+r8]  
000000013F6421A3  mulsd       xmm2,xmm2  
000000013F6421A7  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+18h]  
000000013F6421AD  mov         rax,r8  
000000013F6421B0  add         r8,4  
000000013F6421B4  sub         rax,rcx  
000000013F6421B7  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rbx+rax*8+18h]  
000000013F6421BD  subsd       xmm1,xmm0  
000000013F6421C1  divsd       xmm1,xmm2  
000000013F6421C5  movsd       mmword ptr [r14+r10+10h],xmm1  
000000013F6421CC  add         r10,20h  
000000013F6421D0  cmp         r8,r15  
000000013F6421D3  jb          Owner::callTheInline+0B0h (013F6420B0h)
```

`b.inlineMe(ptr + n);`

```
000000013F6422A4  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rcx+r10*8-10h]  
000000013F6422AB  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx]  
000000013F6422B0  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx-8]  
000000013F6422B6  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F6422BA  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rcx+r8*8-8]  
000000013F6422C1  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rcx-8]  
000000013F6422C6  subsd       xmm1,xmm0  
000000013F6422CA  divsd       xmm1,xmm5  
000000013F6422CE  movsd       mmword ptr [rdi+rcx-8],xmm1  
000000013F6422D4  movsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx-8]  
000000013F6422DA  addsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx+8]  
000000013F6422E0  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx]  
000000013F6422E5  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F6422E9  addsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rcx+r8*8]  
000000013F6422EF  addsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rcx]  
000000013F6422F3  subsd       xmm2,xmm0  
000000013F6422F7  divsd       xmm2,xmm5  
000000013F6422FB  movsd       mmword ptr [rdi+rcx],xmm2  
000000013F642300  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx+8]  
000000013F642306  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx]  
000000013F64230B  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rcx+rbp]  
000000013F642310  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F642314  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rcx+r8*8+8]  
000000013F64231B  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [rcx+8]  
000000013F642320  subsd       xmm1,xmm0  
000000013F642324  divsd       xmm1,xmm5  
000000013F642328  movsd       mmword ptr [rdi+rcx+8],xmm1  
000000013F64232E  movsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rcx+r10*8+18h]  
000000013F642335  addsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rdx+rcx+8]  
000000013F64233B  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [rcx+rbp]  
000000013F642340  mulsd       xmm0,xmm3  
000000013F642344  addsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rcx+r8*8+10h]  
000000013F64234B  addsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [rcx+10h]  
000000013F642350  subsd       xmm2,xmm0  
000000013F642354  divsd       xmm2,xmm5  
000000013F642358  movsd       mmword ptr [r14+rcx],xmm2  
000000013F64235E  add         rcx,20h  
000000013F642362  sub         rax,1  
000000013F642366  jne         Owner::callTheInline+2A4h (013F6422A4h)
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] and the assembly I'm not sure there is much we can help you with.

Comment: I can add the assembly but I regret to inform you that this is the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: It is not *Complete*.  I can't copy and paste this into my own compiler to try it and the code that is being inlined has been removed.

Comment: You might be running into an aliasing issue. Since `b` has automatic storage duration and doesn't have its address escape the method (after inlining), it's easier for the compiler to determine that `b` and `dptr[n]` can't point to the same things (ie. don't alias each other).

Comment: @NathanOliver It was my understanding I should refrain from cluttering the question. I identified the most important parts, and there is not a requirement to "copy and paste it", so I don't appreciate being dismissed like that.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  Without a complete example we can only guess what the actual issue is.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The question was complete and contained enough information to answer it in my opinion.

Comment: Other than assembly (which I subsequently added), could you please identify the parts I am missing in order to address your suggestions, because copy and paste is not mentioned in your link.

Comment: It'd be nice to see the source code that was used to create the assembly you added.

Comment: We can already pretty much answer the general question (by guessing that `inlineMe` accesses `.v`), but for any more detail about what's going on with that big block of asm we'd need source for it.  The Godbolt compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/) is a handy way to look at asm output for a given source, including using debug info to map source lines <-> asm instructions.  But after inlining + optimization that can get approximate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inlining of functions has three main effects:

- It removes the function-call overhead.
- It allows the compiler to optimize across the boundaries of the function.
- It allows the compiler to make hard assumtpions about hardcoded parameters passed to functions. This includes the this pointer to member functions.

Inlining always happens before the C++ code is translated into assembly. The compiler essentially treats an inline function as if the source code of the called function was inserted at the place of the call. Almost. (In reality the compiler usually *also* compiles the inlined function into a plain normal function and assigns weak linkage to it, but this is then not used in the further inlining process. This is not of interest here.)

In your example `a` is a member of `Owner` and `b` is a local variable on the stack. Both `a` and `b` maintain a state `v`.

To address `a` the compiler needs to address it via the this pointer of `Owner`. To address `b` the compiler does not need to use the this pointer of `Owner`, it is just on the stack. This alone already makes quite a difference in the number of instructions. Actually this also depends whether the compiler was allowed to inline `callTheInline()` or not and what the compiler knows about the storage of the `Owner` instance.

The value of `a.v` persists beyond the end of function `callTheInline()`, while `b` does not persist beyond the end of this function. This potentially allows the compiler to omit certain calculations. But `b.v` does not persist beyond the end of the function which allows the compiler to omit calculations `inlineMe()`.

Comment: I tested a modified version of the code above where ```v``` is no longer a state, and instead embers in ```ClassWithInline``` are initialized with the default values when the default constructor is called; as you said it looks like since ```v``` is not maintained, there are fewer instructions. That also makes it clear (in practise) why additional instructions are required for addressing ```a```.

Comment: @Riddick: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Answers from both yourself and @PeterCordes actually fully addressed my question. I picked this one because it was first, but both answers also mention slightly different (and important) points.

Answer (score 1):

**They aren't.**  (Especially when they're just templates.)

**They're inlined before turning into asm** (usually in terms of the compiler's internal representation of data flow, often some kind of SSA).  Much further optimization happens *after* that,  so the actual asm depends on the surrounding code at the point where it inlines, and of course the args and what's done with the return value.

A function with an output arg that's unused in one call site could optimize away the part of the function that calculated it, for example.  Or if one of the args was a compile-time constant, that could *vastly* simplify the resulting asm.  (e.g. `if(x<8)` could become `if(false)` or `if(true)` after inlining and constant propagation.)

---

In your case, one of your loops uses a class member object whose pointers might be pointing anywhere.  You don't show the function *using* `ClassWithInline::v` at all, so it's weird that it's a non-static member function at all instead of just a templated free function.

**But if `ClassWithInline::v` does come into it, `a.inlineMe(ptr + n);` would involve `this.v` and `this.a.v`**, which might or might not point to overlapping memory.  The compiler doesn't know, so has to make conservative assumptions, or emit 2 versions of the loop and check for overlap before running the fast or safe version.  This would defeat auto-vectorization, and require more store/reload to make asm that's correct even in the case of aliasing.

(This is a `struct`, not `class`, so those members are public and callers of this function might have modified those members before calling us.)

**But `b.inlineMe(ptr + n)` uses `this.v` for both pointers, and after inlining the compiler can see that.**

The other memory involved is from `new`, which is known to not overlap with other memory.  i.e. any pre-existing pointers can't be pointing into the buffer returned by `new[]`.  I think MSVC does enough alias-analysis to figure this out.  But given the lack of auto-vectorization, maybe not.

---

BTW, calling both pointers `v` makes it really confusing to think/talk about.

Comment: I apologize about the strange naming, I saw that (just before reading your question) and fixed it. Regarding the templated function, it is because the original code used it like that, and I wanted to maintain that detail in my example. Also, your assumption regarding the pointers is correct; the constants in ```v``` are accessed in the function.

Comment: @Riddick: if this is from real code, does every instance really need its own pointer to a different table of constants?  Could you make the table a `static const T[]` member instead, to remove a level of indirection and any aliasing problems?  If not then maybe the caller can pass a table of constants?  Or maybe you don't have many instances, and it does make sense to have a separate pointer per instance.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I can (and should) do that. The constants are the same, initialized at the start of the program.

Comment: Yup, then do `static const T coefficients[] = initializer_function()` or something.  To make that actually work in C++, you need the array to be inside a wrapper class so you can return it by value (or write a constructor), but it lets you tell the compiler that the values are `static const` and still have them calculated at runtime startup instead of compile time and embedded in the executable.